# How to get a variable input in url after question mark (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am creating a rest api using node js. When I perform a get I want to be able to get some parameters through the url:

```
  app.get("/energy/api/ActualTotalLoad/:AreaName/:Resolution/date/:Year-:Month-:Day?format=:Type", entry.findTwo);
```

But when I do the following: `if(req.query.format!==undefined && req.query.format=="csv")`

It does not get the input. I found similar questions here where the input is not variable, but here the format can either json or csv and I don't wont to write two different app.gets (one for csv and one for json).

Can this be done?

Comment: Why are you using `format=:Type` in the URL?  `req.query.format` will get you the value from the URL.  But, you need to put a meaningful value into the URL on the calling side.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder my question was answered correctly, but for context yes I am using Express

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to make the route with the query params. It will be in `req.query` by default.

so in your case:

```
const app = require('express')();
app.get("/energy/api/ActualTotalLoad/:AreaName/:Resolution/date/:Year-:Month-:Day", (req, res)=>{
  console.dir(req.query.format);
  res.send();
});

app.listen(8080);
```

Then, open `http://localhost:8080/energy/api/ActualTotalLoad/aaa/aaa/date/aaa-aaaa-aaaa?format=csv`

The output will be:

```
'csv'
```